Why am I getting frequent “Password is Locked” notifications?
I keep receiving this notification on my MacBook Pro, regardless of what apps I am running:


“Password is Locked - Touch ID or password needed for current user.”

Is there a way to find logs from where this prompt is coming from?
I suspect it may be a virus? How can I tell.

How often does this happen? Does it happen at regular intervals or at random? Can you make it happen?  If you remember when it started, were any new passwords added on that date? Have you logged out or rebooted since then?

Also, what version of Sequoia are you running? If it's not the latest version (15.2), you should update it.
